# Designing a basic RGB LED blinking circuit

Tags: arduino, led

The circuit:

[image]

Trying to get this just to blink, but can't figure out how.

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}
    
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);   
  delay(250);                     
  digitalWrite(3 , LOW);   
  delay(250);                   
}
```

Pretty much the stock Arduino code, but I don't know why it won't work with multiple LEDs.

EDIT: The LEDs aren't blown out, because they all still work one at a time.

Comment: Hi, it is not visible how you have leds wired (if in parallel or in series) and also you need to tell voltages of leds. It's much better to share sketch in some program than photo of breadboard. Also SO is programming site and this question probably belongs more to [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) as it is not really about C algorithm.

Comment: The voltage for 3 leds in series not enough

Comment: You need to study the operation of LEDs, and then it will be clear what you're doing wrong.  Your code is fine; your wiring is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in your code.

A single standard red LED drops about 1.8 V, and with the proper resistor an Arduino pin can drive such a LED at the right current.

Three LEDs (especially with a blue one among them) in series need more voltage than the Arduino pin can deliver (5 V), so they won't light up. Maybe two LEDs with a recalculated resistor will just about work.

Try leaving out the blue LED; it has the highest voltage drop (about 3 to 3.3 V), so adding one other LED will already go too close to, or beyond, 5 V, and the LEDs won't light up.

You could put the LEDs in parallel, each with their own properly calculated resistor, but the total current you pull in that configuration may exceed the maximum current allowed per Arduino pin (this depends on the Arduino used: about 20 mA for most Arduinos, but only 7 mA for SAMD21-based Arduinos).